# Cant stop datanode and namenode on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I've just ran an example of Apache Mahout clustering in my computer (with hadoop single node installed), I've started hadoop process (jobtracker, tasktracker, datanode, namenode) with the command (found in HADOOP_HOME\bin) start-all.sh. But when I try to use the command stop-all.sh, it says to me that there is no namenode or datanode running, though jps says that both are running.

In the core-site.xml, this is what I have:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>(...)</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

The user who runs hadoop, in my case hduser, is the owner of that directory (/app/hadoop/tmp). I think that formatting namenode could solve my problem, but is there an other solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple set up of hadoop?

Comment: There is something wrong in your installation. But this is off-topic: not a *programming* question.